# $X$ and $X^2$ as discrete random variables

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a discrete random variable with probability distribution $P(X = x)$, what does $X^2$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just like $X$, $X^2$ is a random variable.

A random variable is any measurable function mapping a probability space to the real numbers. You can then compose a random variable with any real function and the result will still be a function mapping from a probability space to the reals.

For example, say I have a random variable $X$ that can take values $\{-1,0,1\}$, each with a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$. The random variable $X^2$ takes a value $x^2$ whenever $X$ takes the value $x$.

This means that $X^2$ can only take values $\{0,1\}$ with probabilities:

- $X^2=0\iff X=0$, therefore $P(X^2=0) = P(X=0)=\frac13$
- $X^2=1\iff (X=1\text{ or }X=-1)$, therefore $P(X^2 = 1) = P(X=1\vee X=-1) = \frac23$